# How to equate set $S = \{ X\mid A_i x_i = b_i; i = 1,\ldots,n\}$ and subsets say $S_i = \{x_i \mid A_i x_i = b_i \}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Sorry for asking a silly question.

Let a matrix $X=[x_1,\ldots,x_n] \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1}$.

> How to equate set $S = \{ X \mid A_i x_i = b_i;  i = 1,\ldots,n\}$ and a subset say $S_i = \{x_i \mid A_i x_i = b_i \}$, where $A_i \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times m}$ and $b_i \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times 1}$?
>
> In other words, how to write the superset $S$ comprising all the subsets $S_i$?

Can I say $S = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n S_i$? Does that mathematically make sense?

---

Edit:

As expected, the union of $S_i$ does not make any sense.

I summarize angryvian's comments below.

We can view the $X$ matrix comprising ordered tuples of $n$ columns such that the set $S$ can be seen as a cartesian product of sets $S_i$, i.e.,
$$S = S_1 \times S_2 \times \cdots \times S_n \ .$$

Comment: If you are ok with a matrix $X$ being viewed as an ordered tuple of $n$ columns, then you could write $S = S_1 \times \cdots \times S_n$.

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly is the object you wish to express? Note that $S_i$ is an (affine) subset of $\Bbb{R}^{m \times 1}$, but $S$ is a subset of $\Bbb{R}^{m \times n}$. How are $S$ and $S_i$ actually related? As far as I can tell, $S$ is not the union of the $S_i$s, since $S$ contains matrices of different dimensions to the matrices in $S_i$.

Comment: @angryvian, thank You. I think I am happy to view the columns of X as ordered tuple of $n$ columns.

Comment: @TheoBendit: I wanted to express the affine set $S$ in terms of $S_i$. I agree that the union of $S_i$ doesn't make sense at all. That's why I asked this silly question. However, angryvian's suggestion makes sense to me since I can view the columns of $X$ as an ordered tuples.